# Reshowing database results in inputs when linked back to the page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am using ColdFusion 16, HTML5, JavaScript and MSSQL for my project.

I have a form with Name, Email, Billing and Shipping Address and Phone number that once the form is submitted it inserts that info into the database. On another page I have a link to go back to that same page in case the user wants to change the info.

How do I display what is in the database back in those fields?

Also how do I have the page look exactly the same as from when it was left.

For example the box checked with the arrow saying billing and shipping is the same. Or have my hidden fields being shown if they were being shown when the page was submitted.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">Name of owner:</label>
            <cfoutput><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First" maxlength="100" required="yes" value="" /></cfoutput>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <cfoutput><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="middlename" id="middlename" placeholder="Middle" maxlength="100" value="" /></cfoutput>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <cfoutput><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last"  maxlength="100" required="yes" value="" /></cfoutput>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If your user has already submitted the info, your page has changed from an `INPUT` page to an `UPDATE` page. You can query your insert table for the record they submitted and output that info back into the form. Is your box for Billing and Shipping Same stored in your database? If not, you can use some query magic to return a value for that if the db's Billing and Shipping addressess match.

Comment: The link that goes back to the page could include the ID of the record that was added. When displaying the form, see if the ID exists, and if it does, query the database for the data.

Comment: You wouldn't want to pass an ID through a link if you can help it. At least not without a LOT of validation to prevent anyone from editing any record they wanted. It would be better to send the value through the session or some other less easily modifiable identifier.

Comment: Agreed... you would need to validate any modifications to the record, and you would probably want to use some sort of uuid or non-guessable ID if you were to send it via the URL. Putting the ID in the session could be a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're on your Address page, you can use a query to populate the page.

You'll need some sort of id to verify the record you want to edit. I'm assuming the shipping record will be entered based on some sort of session identifier.

My theoretical database setup:

**BillingAddress**

```
| ID | Address1      | etc... |
===============================
| 1  | 123 Sesame St | ...... |
```

**ShippingAddress**

```
| ID | Address1      | etc... |
===============================
| 1  | 123 Sesame St | ...... |
```

On the initial form, we can query the database to see if there are any records for the user.

```
<cfquery name="getShippingAddress" datasource="myDSN">
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, Address1, etc... 
    FROM ShippingAddress
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="getBillingDetails" datasource="myDSN">
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, Address1, etc... 
    FROM BillingAddress
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
```

*NOTE: If we can be assured that there will never be more than one row for an `ID`, then we can skip the `TOP 1`.*

When we write out our form, we can output existing values into the form.

```
<cfoutput>
    <input type="text" name="shippingAddress1"
        value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(getShippingAddress.Address1)#" />
</cfoutput>
```

In the form, there is a checkbox (`BillingShippingSame`) to determine if the Billing Address is the same as the Shipping Address.

We can set this value with some additional checks.

```
<cfif BillingShippingSame = getShippingAddress.Address1 = getBillingAddress.Address1 AND .... >
```

This just says that if the Address fields in both queries are the same, then set `BillingShippingSame` to `true` otherwise `false`. If all of the fields in both queries are the same, you can also convert both queries to JSON and compare them. (`serializeJSON(getShippingAddress) == serializeJSON(getBillinAddress)`). This will save some typing if you have multiple fields that need to be checked, but they'll only serialize the same if the fields in both queries are the same. Then just set the value in you checkbox input.

```
<input type="text" name="BillingShippingSame" <cfif BillingShippingSame>checked="checked"</cfif> />
```

And if you wanted to, you could javascript the page so that if `BillingShippingSame` is checked, it either disables the Billing form fields, or just continues to populate them with what was returned from the database.

Back to our workflow. Since HTML won't pass a checkbox if it isn't checked, then just look in the `form` scope to see if that box was checked. If it was, then set the Billing details to the Shipping details.

Insert/Update queries:

```
<cfset cleanShippingAddress1 = cleanString(form.ShippingAddress)>
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"BillingShippingSame")>
    <cfset cleanBillingAddress1 = cleanString(form.ShippingAddress)>
    <cfset cleanOtherBillingFields = .....>
<cfelse>
    <cfset cleanBillingAddress1 = cleanString(form.BillingAddress)>
    <cfset cleanOtherBillingFields = .....>
</cfif>
<cfset cleanOtherFields = cleanString(....)>

<cfquery name="UpsertShippingAddress" datasource="myDSN">
    UPDATE ShippingAddress
    SET ShippingAddress1 = <cfqueryparam value="#cleanShippingAddress1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        , OtherShippingFields = 
            <cfqueryparam value="#cleanOtherShippingFields#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        , ...
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
      INSERT INTO ShippingAddress ( ID, ShippingAddress1, OtherShippingFields, ....)
      VALUES (
             <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#cleanShippingAddress1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#cleanOtherShippingFields#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , ...
      ) ;
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="UpsertBillingAddress" datasource="myDSN">
    UPDATE BillingAddress
    SET BillingAddress1 = <cfqueryparam value="#cleanBillingAddress1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        , OtherShippingFields = 
            <cfqueryparam value="#cleanOtherBillingFields#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        , ...
    WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
      INSERT INTO BillingAddress ( ID, BillingAddress1, OtherBillingFields, ....)
      VALUES (
           <cfqueryparam value="#session.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#cleanBillingAddress1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , cfqueryparam value="#cleanOtherBillingFields#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , ...
      ) ;
</cfquery>
```

I tend to err on the side of paranoia when it comes to `form` or `url` or other untrustworthy inputs. My `cleanString` function would do various sanitations on the string before it goes into the database.

I also used a SQL pattern that `UPDATE`s the database, and if no rows were inserted (`@@ROWCOUNT=0` >> ID wasn't found), then it will `INSERT` instead.